# Contextual Help In J

Tags: j

When messing around with Haskell using GHC, I can use various meta-commands like `:i` or `:t` to find out some information about an identifier. In REBOL, I can use functions like `help` and sometimes `source` to get extremely detailed information on a REBOL word.

If such a facility exists for J, I've somehow missed it. Do any J-ers out there know of anything built-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight the primitive or J library verb and hit Ctrl-F1. Instant help in html form in your browse if it's a primitive, script documentation for J library verbs.

EDIT:

Or you can use the verb defined to do that, `help_j_`:

```
help_j_ 'i.' NB. Opens didot.htm
help_j_ 'help_j_' NB. Opens \system\extras\util\jadefull.ijs in scriptdoc
```